# Should window variables be considered API?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, api-design

Take React for instance. React 15 and 16 are not compatible with eachother, yet they both set the `window.React` variable.

Now consider an application which can host independent components that have their own dependencies. One component depends on React 15 and one depends on React 16. When these two components are loaded, they will conflict with eachother because they're both referencing the same window variable.

For this reason, is it correct to treat window variables as API? Or am I missing something.

Comment: Is this a problem you are having an issue with specifically, or are you just trying to get opinions about theoretical cases?

Comment: Oh I don't have a specific problem I'm just wondering if it's best practice to treat window variables as API in this case.

Comment: what does that mean, exactly?  how would you treat them as anything other than what they are:  properties of the `window` global object?

Comment: Also, this is not always the case: registering `React` to the global object is not a default. If you use a bundle builder like webpack there's nothing exposed on the global window object (if you don't want to explicitly).

Comment: @LucaFabbri I didn't know you could do that with webpack, could you link me somewhere explaining that process? I'm wondering how webpack could stop React from putting itself on the global object.

Comment: @Ogen if you are using create-react-app it already works that way, so you can have two different app with different React version of the same page although I'm not sure they will be 100% compatible because IFRC old React versions register event handlers on the document.